# Access data directly form the jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access data from a plugin and use this directly in one of the plugin options/defaults. Never done this so how can I do this?

```
;(function(root, factory){

    if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd){
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    }else{
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }

}(this, function($){          

    var pluginName = 'somePlugin';

    function Plugin(element, options){

        this.obj = $(element);      
        this.o   = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);

        this.init();
    };

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function(){ 

            // add a class to all elments with the class name 'wrap_div'
            $('.wrap_div').addClass('wrapped_div');

            // count the total of the newly added class(see below)
            var totalElements = $('wrapped_div').length;

            // for this example 
            alert( o.option_one );

        },  

        destroy: function(){ }      

    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function(option, param) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this   = $(this);
            var data    = $this.data(pluginName);
            var options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
            if(!data){ 
              $this.data(pluginName, (data = new Plugin(this, options)))
            }
            if(typeof option == 'string'){
                 data[option](param);
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        option_one: ''
    };

    $[pluginName] = function() {
        var $body = $(document.body);
        $body[pluginName].apply($body, arguments);
    }

}));


// call the plugin
$.somePlugin({
    option_one: totalElements// access the var for the plugin   
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `totalElements` not appear defined outside of `Plugin.prototype.init` ? What is expected result ?

Comment: @RocketHazmat in the example above im trying to get the total of the elements which have the newly added class and make this data available outside the plugin to use it in one of the plugin option during the plugin call.